# Redirect an URL by default, and show the original page when ?redirect=false is shown

Tags: asp.net, redirect

I have a question about URL redirection.

Now I have the .aspx file of a page. And I have added the following part at the beginning of the .aspx file:

```
<script runat="server">
  protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
  {
    Response.Redirect("New URL");
    base.OnLoad(e);
  }
</script>
```

So the old URL is redirected to the new one. This part works well.

But when I add a `?redirect=false` at the end of the old URL, it still redirects me to the new page.

Is there a way that I can see the old page?

Comment: this is how computer works! 
you have to tell it what to do :)
add an if Statment.

Answer (score 2):

Well... you actually need to test for that query parameter.

something like:

```
if ((Request.QueryString["redirect"] == null) || (Request.QueryString["redirect"] != 'false'))
  Response.Redirect("NEW URL");
}
base.OnLoad(e);
```

The test for null is there in case the `redirect` parameter wasn't passed in.